# Balls are placed into 3 urns. Expected time until some urn has 100 balls.

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-methods

We have $3$ urns. At each round a ball is placed is placed into one of them, at random, with uniform probability. The game stops when some urn has $100$ balls.

What is expected duration of the game (number of rounds)?

Results from a simulation:

[image]

Comment: each round we pick one enemy and we hit him once

Comment: yes at random||

Comment: In coding:  you can design a program that randomly increments one of three ints until one of them is $100$.  Record the number of increments, and rerun.  You should see a convergence towards a particular number given a large enough number of simulations.

Comment: What is the probability that  enemy $i$ is hit if enemy $i$ has been chosen?

Comment: @callculus we do not consider enemy attacks

Comment: @AndrewChin sure I wrote this simulation but it is not helping me at all, sure that you can have number through simulations but I would like to get formula (if it's possible)

Comment: So a chosen enemy is a hit enemy?

Comment: Does not look trivial, but probably has been studied here. Thinking. Numerically (not simulation) I get 274.918644

Comment: @callculus yes.

Comment: @quester Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @quester I´ve calculated the sum by using wolfram alpha, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28i%3D0%29%5E%2899%29+sum_%28j%3D0%29%5E%2899%29+%28100%2Bi%2Bj%29*%5Cfrac%7B%28100%2Bi%2Bj%29%21%7D%7B100%21j%21i%21%7D+%281%2F3%29%5Ei+%281%2F3%29%5Ej+%281%2F3%29%5E100). The result is  $\large{252.5}$

Comment: @quester You wrote that you don´t need numbers. But you should start to analyze the problem. For instance, my result does not match the graph you´ve posted. My first question is why?

Comment: @callculus what do you mean? avg of this data is **274.9...** which matches result of leonbloy

Comment: @quester I don´t know what the mean at the graph is. But it does not clearly matches my result where I used your formula. Do you think your formula is wrong?

Comment: formula is for calculating expected number of steps... although when I come to think of it I took it from multinomial distribtion and I ignored some vectors so... probably sumation of probabilities will give value $<1$ so there should be magic component $1/prob_{sum}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99057/discussion-between-quester-and-callculus).

Comment: @callculus I wonder where the mistake in your formula is (I would calculate it the exactly like that)

Comment: @Sudix problem with formula is that there should be $\sum p = 1$, but unfortunately it is $\sum p < 1$ it should be summed up and then multiplied by inverse $\sum p = c => p_{new} = \frac{p}{c}$ then $EX = \sum x p_{new}$

Comment: @quester The idea was to fix that the first bowl always gets 100 pulls, and then sum all tuples (0,0) to (99,99) for the other two bowls up: $$\sum _{j=0}^{99} \left(\sum _{i=0}^{99}(100+i+j) \frac{\binom{i+j+100}{100}
   \binom{i+j}{i}}{3^{i+j+100}}\right)$$ So, if anything, I expected that without the $(100+i+j)$, the sum would sum up to $1/3$, but instead it sums up to $\approx 0.89$. Also, even if I norm the  probabilities of the events so their sum goes to1, I get as expected value $275.5308620$, which is too far off from the other result. Somewhere there is still a hole in my reasoning

Comment: let's say that I thought about this problem for a long time and I know it's not trivial, althougt very fun!

Comment: @sudix Those are the probabilities for the state (100,i,j). However, that does not mean that this 100 was reached in the *last* placement of the ball. You can reach the state (100,i,j) via (99,i,j) but also via (100,i-1,j) or (100,i,j-1). See in my answer where I compute the case that a an urn has 100 in it *in the last ball placement* by computing the probability that the urn has 99 in it (and no then you have 1/3 probability to reach 100 in the next step).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected time can be expressed in terms of the incomplete gamma function as follows (inspired by [this paper](https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Double-dixie-cup-problem.pdf) and comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370609/integral-involving-gamma-incomplete-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

In general: We want the expected value of the time to wait $T$ until one of the $3$ urns contains $n$ ($=100$) balls. Then

$$E_{n}[T] = \sum_{t=1}^\infty P(T\ge t) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty p_{n}(t) \tag1$$

where $p_{n}(t) $ is the probability that after $t$ rounds ($t$ balls) all $3$ urns have less than $n$ balls. But this is equivalent to

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}\sum_{z=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{3^{x+y+z}} \frac{(x+y+z)!}{x! \, y! \, z!} \tag2$$

Further, we use a [property of the (upper) incomplete gamma function](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/06/01/04/01/02/0004/):

$$\begin{align}
\left( \frac{\Gamma(n,a)}{\Gamma(n)} \right)^3 &= \left( e^{-a} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^r}{r!} \right)^3 \\&=  
e^{-3a} \sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}\sum_{z=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^{x+y+z}}{x! \, y! \, z!} \tag3
 \end{align}$$

Integrating and using $\int_0^\infty \exp(-3a) a^p da = p!/3^{p+1}$ we get

$$ \int_0^\infty  \left( \frac{\Gamma(n,a)}{\Gamma(n)} \right)^3 da= 
\sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}\sum_{z=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{3^{x+y+z+1}} 
 \frac{(x+y+z)!}{x! \, y! \, z!} \tag4$$

and finally

$$E_{n}[T]  = 3 \int_0^\infty  \left( \frac{\Gamma(n,a)}{\Gamma(n)} \right)^3 da \tag5$$

More in general, if we have $d$ urns:

$$E_{n,d}[T]  = d \int_0^\infty  \left( \frac{\Gamma(n,a)}{\Gamma(n)} \right)^d da \tag6$$

This can be evaluated numerically, I don't know about asymptotics (asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370609/integral-involving-gamma-incomplete-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Empirically , it seems that  $E = 3 n - \beta \sqrt{n} +O(1)$ where $\beta \approx 2.5$

---

And here's a numerical recursive computation (in Java):

```
public class MSE3368225 {

    static Double[] cache = new Double[(1<<21)];

    static double ex(int x, int y, int z) {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0)
            return 0;
        if (x > 127 || y > 127 || z > 127) 
            throw new RuntimeException("Out of range");
        int k = (x << 14) | (y << 7) | z; // packs three variables in one integer
        Double d = cache[k];
        if (d == null) {
            d = 1 + (ex(x - 1, y, z) + ex(x, y - 1, z) + ex(x, y, z - 1)) / 3.0;
            cache[k] = d;
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ex(100, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

This solves the recursion

$$g(x,y,z)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text {if $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$}\\
1+ \frac13\left(g(x-1,y,z)+g(x,y-1,z)+g(x,y,z-1)\right) & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

where $g(x,y,z)$ is the expected remaining time, when there remains $(x,y,z)$ balls for each urn.

The result is $E_{100}[T]=274.9186440$

---

Some values

```
  n     E
  2  2.888889 
  3  5.049383 
  4  7.348270 
  5  9.734204
 10  22.34468
 20  48.99126
 50  132.3676
100  274.9186
```

Comment: noticed that if it would be optimized like (x,y,z) always would be sorted then number of steps would be greatly reduced

Comment: and how did you computed this integral $E(L, N)$?

Comment: You mean how I evaluated it or how I got it? If the former: numerically - and I checked that it agreed with the code above.

Comment: I mean how did you figured out this formula with integral and fraction with gamma functions, I wish I worked more with gamma functions and I would like to develop intuition behind gamma functions in probability theory

Comment: @quester I added an explanation

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks a lot! Just a comment that I linked here from [Expected number of rolls until a number appears $k$ times](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/475821/1352), which is of course the exact same problem (with $d$ the number of sides of the die, and $k=100$ here).

Answer (score 4):

#### Computation of the distribution

Let $n$ be the number of balls to draw. Let $m$ be the number of urns. Let $k$ be the target number of balls when the game stops.

You could express the probability to reach a stop in $n$ balls in terms of the probability that the number of balls in each urn is $k-1$ or less (the cumulative distribution).

- The number of ways to put $n$ balls into $m$ urns is $m^n$ (with or without reaching the stop condition).
- The number of ways to put $n$ balls into $m$ urns but not having reached the stop condition (that is having at most $k-1$ in each of them) can be found by enumerating over the set $S$ of vectors $\vec{k}$ (the numbers $(k_i)$ depicting the the number of balls in each $i$-th urn) that satisfy the condition $$\sum_i k_i = n \quad \text{and} \quad  \forall i:0 \leq k_i < k$$ And
  for each of the vector $\vec{k}$ (a set of numbers $k_1,k_2,k_3$) that satisfies these
  conditions we compute the the number of ways to distribute the balls
  into the urns with those numbers which is $$\text{number of ways to
     put $k_i$ balls in urn $i$} = \frac{n!}{\prod_i{k_i!}}$$ Then we take the sum over all of this $$P(N \leq n) = \frac{1}{m^n}\sum_{\vec{k} \in S} \frac{n!}{\prod_{k_i\in \vec{k}}{k_i!}} $$
  where the sum over $\vec{k} \in S$ means the summation over all vectors with numbers $k_i$ that satisfy the conditions and the product over $k_i \in \vec{k}$ means the product with all $k_i$ in the $\vec{k}$.

See below for an implementation in R code:

[image: output image from code]

```
# computation
n <- 99
sum <- rep(0,3*n+1)
for (k1 in 0:n) {
  for (k2 in 0:n) {
    for (k3 in 0:n) {
      t = (k1+k2+k3)
      sum[t+1] = sum[t+1]+exp(lfactorial(t)-lfactorial(k1)-lfactorial(k2)-lfactorial(k3))
    }
  }
}
x <- c(0:(3*n))
Xcum <- c(sum/3^x,0)

# simulation
set.seed(1)

draw <- function() {
  s <- sample(c(1:3),size = 300, replace=TRUE)
  min(which((cumsum(s==1)==100) | (cumsum(s==2)==100) | (cumsum(s==3)==100)))
}
q <- replicate(10^5,draw())

# computation using beta function

drn <- function(n,k) {
  a <- max(0,n-2*k+1)
  b <- min(k-1,n-k)
  choose(n-1,k-1) * 2^(n-k) / 3^(n-1) *
      ( zipfR::Ibeta(0.5,n-k-b+1,b+1)/beta(n-k-b+1,b+1) - 
        zipfR::Ibeta(0.5,n-(k-1)-(a-1),(a-1)+1)/beta(n-(k-1)-(a-1),(a-1)+1) )
  #choose(n-1,k-1) * 2^(n-k) / 3^(n-1) * (pbinom(b,n-k,0.5)-pbinom(a-1,n-k,0.5))
}
drn <- Vectorize(drn)


#plotting both together

h <- hist(q, breaks=c(0:298)+0.5, xlim=c(200,300),
          xlab = "N", ylab = "probability", freq = FALSE, main="")
lines(1:298,-diff(Xcum),col=2)
lines(c(100:298),drn(c(100:298),100),col=3)
```

---

#### multinomial distribution

You can view this as related to the [multinomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) which has the pdf

$$\frac {n!}{k_1! k_2! ... k_m!} p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} ... p_m^{k_m} $$

which becomes for equal $p_i = 1/m $ the following

$$\frac {1}{m^n}\frac {n!}{k_1! k_2! ... k_m!} $$

which shows similarity with the expresssion before. Then the probability that for $n$ draws you did not reach 100 yet is equal to the probability that in 100 draws each $k_i<100$. And you can see the computation of you probability density as the computation of the CDF for the multinomial distribution.

---

#### Expression in terms of regularized incomplete beta function

For the case of three urns we may write an explicit expression for the probability in terms of the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).

The probability that there are in the $n$-th draw $k$ balls in the first urn and less than $k$ in the others is, is equal to the 1/3 of the probability that there are in the $n-1$ draw $l= k-1$ balls in the first urn and equal or less than $l$ in the others is :

$$\begin{array}{rcrl}
P_{k_1=l=k-1,k_2 \leq l,k_3 \leq l \vert n-1} &=& &\sum_{a \leq k_2 \leq b} \frac {1}{3^{n-1}}\frac {(n-1)!}{l! k_2! (n-1-l-k_2)!} \\
& = & \frac{(n-1)!}{l! 3^{n-1}} &\sum_{a \leq k_2 \leq b} \frac {1}{k_2! (n-1-l-k_2)!} \\
& = & {{n-1}\choose{l}} \frac{2^{n-1-l}}{3^{n-1}}&  \sum_{a \leq k_2 \leq b} \underbrace{{n-1-l\choose{k_2}} \frac{1}{2^{n-1-l}}}_{\text{this is a binomial distribution}} \\
& = & {{n-1}\choose{k-1}} \frac{2^{n-k}}{3^{n-1}} & \left( I_{1/2}(n-k-b+1,b+1) - I_{1/2}(n-k-a+2,a) \right)
\end{array}$$

with $a = max(0,n-2k+1)$ and $b = min(k-1,n-k)$

---

#### Computation of the expectation value

In the first part we computed $P(n>k) = 1-P(n\leq k)$. To obtain the mean you can sum over all of these. $\mu = \sum 1-P(n\leq k)$. This will give:

$$\sum_{k_1=0}^{99}\sum_{k_2=0}^{99}\sum_{k_3=0}^{99} \frac{1}{3^{k_1+k_2+k_3}} \frac{(k_1+k_2+k_3)!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!} = 274.9186 $$

Comment: nice solution, specially in the first part. But $(k_1,k_2,k_3)$ is not a set, it is a triple (vector)